# How can I export calculated fields in Cognito Forms to Excel?

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a calculated field on my form, however it is not exported when I export to Excel.

How can I make the calculated fields be part of the export?

Answer (score 1):

Isa,

I work with the Cognito Development Team.
I was able to reproduce the issue you describe and it appears for some reason calculated fields are not being included on a Forms Entry Export.

I am creating an internal bug report for this issue so we can get one of the team members to take a look at it.

I see you already created a bug report through Cognito Forms so I will keep that issue open until we have a fix in place.

Comment: Support for exporting calculated fields will be included in our next release!

Comment: The support for exporting the calculation field was released on Friday. You should now be able to export forms that have a calculation field.